How to integrate AxxonOne using a socket.IO server side?
I have tried way too many things to explain but nothing seems to work when I try to put the web socket or socket into my code I have tried what the documentation mentions like the
ws://[user_name]:[password]@[IP address]:[port]/[prefix]/events or POST and even GET from the documentation but nothing seems to be working
I tried the following but I got an error that fetch didn't support the ws process which makes sense, but then what I am to use?
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

const getFaceController = async (io, req, res) => {
    try {
        const USERNAME = process.env.USERNAME;
        const PASSWORD = process.env.PASSWORD;
        const IP_ADDRESS = process.env.IP_ADDRESS;
        const PORT = process.env.PORT;
        const requestData = req.body;
        const response = await axios.get(`ws://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@${IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT}/[prefix]/events`, requestData);

        const responseData = response.data;

        io.emit('data', responseData);

        res.json(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching data' });
    }
};

module.exports = getFaceController;


I also tried:
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();

const getFaceController = async (io, req, res) => {
    try {
        const USERNAME = process.env.USERNAME;
        const PASSWORD = process.env.PASSWORD;
        const IP_ADDRESS = process.env.IP_ADDRESS;
        const PORT = process.env.PORT;
        const requestData = req.body;
        const response = await axios.get(`http://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@${IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT}/[prefix]/events`, requestData);

        const responseData = response.data;

        io.emit('data', responseData);

        res.json(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching data' });
    }
};

module.exports = getFaceController;

And obtained a timed out connection error, I'm pretty much at the end my rope, any ideas?
